# Android Studio cannot recognize LG V10 (Mac)

Tags: android

My LG V10 says it is in USB debugging mode, but android studio won't recognize it. I have trie MTP <--> PTP

Has anyone solved this issue?

My computer is not prompting to authorize the device when I plug it in, is this the issue?

I can use android filetransfer

Comment: Try opening a terminal and running `adb devices`. If `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` is not in your PATH, you will need to add it or run `adb` from that directory or with the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install LG Suite first.

Comment: Also have in MTP mode

Comment: Tried to accomplish this using an LG V10. I cannot seem to connect, either to Android Studio or LG Suite. I do not see an option for MTP mode on the device but Windows said that it connected as such, still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me was helped installing **LG Bridge**, because LG Suite is only for media and not for debugging.